# NSCoding - reuse object for writing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a Singleton which has an NSMutableArray containing a Class, the Class contains the proper NSCoding routines to encode/decode the data - it all works fine.

However I'd now like to also save data that is not part of the Class (array), but instead is part of the Singleton and is not specific to each item in the Class/array. So I've added the appropriate code in the Singleton including:

```
    BOOL            alarmIsOn;
    ...
    @property(nonatomic,assign)   BOOL            alarmIsOn;
    ...
    @synthesize alarmIsOn;
    ...
    [encoder encodeBool:alarmIsOn forKey:@"alarmison"];
    ...
    alarmIsOn=[decoder decodeBoolForKey:@"alarmison"];
```

When I save my data I previously used this which works perfectly:

```
GlobalData *globDat=[GlobalData getSingleton];
NSData *encodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:globDat.allMsgs];
[encodedObject writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
```

Now I'd like to add the following to include the additional data from the Singleton:

```
encodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:globDat.alarmIsOn];
[encodedObject writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
```

However it gives me this error in Xcode:

```
 Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Implicit conversion of 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') to 'id' is disallowed with ARC
```

And this warning:

```
Semantic Issue: Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'BOOL' (aka 'signed char') to parameter of type 'id'
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

Comment: I have resolved this completely now - DRVic is right regarding the BOOL (see below) and I have contained the allMsgs array and the single  objects into an NSDictionary, then I save the NSDictionary to the plist - works perfectly. I can post the final code if someone wants it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is that 
    globDat.alarmIsOn
is a bool and

```
NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:
```

wants an

```
id
```

which is another word for an opaque pointer to an object.  A bool is just a byte.  How exactly you want to fix it is up to you.  To use that routine requires an object.

Comment: You can [NSNumber numberWithBool:(BOOL)]

Comment: @DRVic So I understand, this is not a problem when the bool is part of a Class then added to an NSMutableArray - But when it is "alone", it is a problem? Also, the rest of my structure is ok?

Comment: @AdamShiemke So I could do this? `encodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:(globDat.isAlarm)]];`

Comment: @AdamShiemke Ok, I tried it but I can't see if it works because I can't read the data - what is the converse usage of NSNumber... when I retrieve my data with this: `globDat.allMsgs=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:codedData]`

Comment: Right.  This is one of many possible ways of handling it.  Alternatively you could make the entire singleton NSCoding compliant and then pass it.  Should you ever add more than the single bool that you are currently trying to archive, you wouldn't need to change this part of the code (but you'd still need to keep the whole thing NSCoding compliant).

Comment: @wayneh I think your question is how to get to a bool from an NSNumber?  That would be boolValue.